# Codenameone - How can Picker control display 12(Hour) for midnight

Tags: codenameone

Picker control display 00:16am for mdnight. I would like to display 12:16am instaead of 00:16am. Please advise how can I correc the following code.

Code:

```
Picker timePicker = new Picker();
timePicker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_TIME);
timePicker.setShowMeridiem(true);
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
timePicker.setTime(time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 + time.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
timePicker.setEnabled(false);
timePicker.setUIID("TextField");
UITimer.timer(1000, true, this, () -> {
time.setTime(new Date());
timePicker.setTime(time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 + time.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
timePicker.repaint();
});
```

[image: midnight time in 12-hour format]
[image: Evening Time in 12-hour format]

Answer (score 1):

This line of code makes the time in a 12 hour format where midnight is represented as 12. If you set it to false, then midnight is 0. That's just the way 12hr vs 24hr hour time is.

```
setShowMeridiem(true)
```

Comment: I have set the time with setShowMeridiem(true) and everythign works fine in 12 hours format (AM/PM) except midnight display as 00: 16am instead of 12:16 am. AM I doing anything wrong in the code?

Comment: If you can come up with a simple date format that satisfies your requirements you can use `myPicker.setFormatter(format)`. Otherwise you need to derive `Picker` and override `protected void updateValue()` and invoke `setText` from there with the way you want the times to appear

Comment: @ShaiAlmog This actually might be a bug, at least in the simulator. When I add a barebones time picker with setShowMeridiem(true), the picker defaults to 0:00am. If I click it, it shows a 0 in the hour slot overlaying a 12. If I keep the hour at 0 and change the minutes, it seems to work but once I switch the hour from 0 or click on the 0, it changes to 12 and from there on out any combination of minutes results in PM even if AM is selected. This is not the case for hours 1-11.

Comment: @Nick Correct. Even I faced same issue both in simulator and in IOS.

Comment: OK, in that case I suggest filing an issue on that. There might be an edge case with meridiem.